# Android SDK Compiling Issue?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I tried and searched a long time for a solution but I was unable to find it, so I hope you can help me here :)

Here's my problem:

I started creating an Andoid App using the adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030 and had to upgrade to adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321. I now did several changes to the app and I try to run it, but it always shows outdated data. I had some activites and added them to the Manifest and they worked, but then I did some changes including the deletion of these activities. I removed them from the Manifest, I deleted their layouts, deleted all of their classes and took care they are never launched in the other activities.

Now when I try to run the app in the Emulator I'm still seeing the old activities with their menu exactly the same as it was before. One was the old Launcher Activity and got removed, but the emulator still shows the old deleted one.

I already searched all files and did a fulltext search using Sublime covering all files but the snippets I searched for where I'm sure they existed before can't be found.

Do you have a clue why it's compiling old code parts and where this is coming from?

Even if I'm renaming the .apk file in the "bin" folder a new file is created that's exactly the same one.

I hope you can help me :)

Best regards Christian

Comment: delete the build folder

Comment: also: remove the app from the emulator before you restart the debugging process. You might, with all your changes, actually have changed the signature of your app (different package). That would explain the phantom activities, at the very least.